# Display Repeatable Meta Box Content

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I'm using the following repeatable meta box code in my functions.php:

```
    /**
 * Repeatable Custom Fields in a Metabox
 * Author: Helen Hou-Sandi
 *
 * From a bespoke system, so currently not modular - will fix soon
 * Note that this particular metadata is saved as one multidimensional array (serialized)
 */

function hhs_get_sample_options() {
    $options = array (
        'Option 1' => 'option1',
        'Option 2' => 'option2',
        'Option 3' => 'option3',
        'Option 4' => 'option4',
    );

    return $options;
}
add_action('admin_init', 'hhs_add_meta_boxes', 1);
function hhs_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'repeatable-fields', 'Emergency Contacts', 'hhs_repeatable_meta_box_display', 'team', 'normal', 'default');
}
function hhs_repeatable_meta_box_display() {
    global $post;
    $repeatable_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);
    $options = hhs_get_sample_options();
    wp_nonce_field( 'hhs_repeatable_meta_box_nonce', 'hhs_repeatable_meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
            var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
            row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
            row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
            return false;
        });

        $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%">Name</th>
            <th width="40%">Phone Number</th>
            <th width="8%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    if ( $repeatable_fields ) :

    foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" value="<?php if($field['name'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['name'] ); ?>" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="phone[]" value="<?php if ($field['phone'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['phone'] ); else echo 'http://'; ?>" /></td>

        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    else :
    // show a blank one
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="phone[]" value="" /></td>

        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
    <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="phone[]" value="" /></td>

        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
    <?php
}
add_action('save_post', 'hhs_repeatable_meta_box_save');
function hhs_repeatable_meta_box_save($post_id) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['hhs_repeatable_meta_box_nonce'] ) ||
    ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['hhs_repeatable_meta_box_nonce'], 'hhs_repeatable_meta_box_nonce' ) )
        return;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;

    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'repeatable_fields', true);
    $new = array();
    $options = hhs_get_sample_options();

    $names = $_POST['name'];
    $phones = $_POST['phone'];

    $count = count( $names );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        if ( $names[$i] != '' ) :
            $new[$i]['name'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $names[$i] ) );

            if ( $phones[$i] == '' )
                $new[$i]['phone'] = '';
            else
                $new[$i]['phone'] = stripslashes( $phones[$i] ); // and however you want to sanitize
        endif;
    }
    if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields', $new );
    elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields', $old );
}

add_action( 'init', 'team_contacts_posttype' );
```

I just need to know how I can display each piece separately. I've tried the following as well as a few other things in my frontend, to no avail:

```
<?php
        $member_contact_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tcp', true);
        $emergency_contact_meta = get_post_custom(get_the_ID(), 'repeatable_fields', true);
        $emerency_contact_name = $emergency_contact_meta['name'];
        $emergency_contact_phone = $emergency_contact_meta['phone'];
        the_content();
        echo $emergency_contact_meta;
        echo '<strong>Phone: </strong>' . $member_contact_meta . '<br />';
        echo '<strong>Emergency Contacts:</strong><br />';
        foreach ($emergency_contact_meta as $emergency_contact_metas)
        echo $emergency_contact_name . ' - ' . $emergency_contact_phone;
    ?>
```

the tcp meta is separate and working fine, but I just don't know how to grab the repeated content meta and display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tested and working version of the template code, which displays the repeatable `$emergency_contact_meta` correctly:

```
$member_contact_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'tcp', true );
echo '<strong>Phone: </strong>' . $member_contact_meta . '<br />';

$emergency_contact_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'repeatable_fields', true);

if ( $emergency_contact_meta ) {
    echo '<strong>Emergency Contacts:</strong><br />';

    foreach ( $emergency_contact_meta as $emergency_contact_metas ) {
        echo '<strong>' . esc_html( $emergency_contact_metas['name'] ) .'</strong> ' . esc_html( $emergency_contact_metas['phone'] ) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

The main issue in the original code was the use of `get_post_custom()` when it appeared you were just trying to get the meta data for the repeatable fields, `repeatable_fields`. [`get_post_custom()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) gets **all** of the meta fields for a particular post.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly, and thanks for helping me understand why.

Comment: You got it, Trenton!